# Column aliasing while copying a table in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, column-alias

Hi I was copying a employees table in `HR` schema with query:

`Create table copy_employees as ( select last_name,salary*12 from employees);`

But the error shows that salary needs to be aliased.

After I did `salary*12 as sal` it worked.

My question is why is this aliasing needed?

Answer (score 4):

a `CTAS` ( `Create Table As Select` ) statement is just like a `Create Table DDL statement` in which column naming has some conventions, such as using

- `the underscore "_"`
- `the dollar sign "$"`
- `pound sign "#"`

  in a column name is allowed, but asterisk `"*"` ( like in your case ) is not allowed to use, so it's impossible to create a table containing a column with an asterisk. In this case, Oracle tries to use the expression `salary*12` as the column name and fails.

Comment: Spot on - might be worth noting explicitly that by default, Oracle uses the expression itself as the column name if no alias is given (in this case, it tries to use `salary*12`).

Comment: @frank it tries to use salary*12 and fails.. Aliasing is therefore mandatory. But why?

Comment: How exactly would you call that column, @Atul? Did you ever try to `create table test (salary*12    number);` ? `salary * 12` is an expression; give it a name. Why? Because that's how it goes.